# How do you correct when Facebook picks the wrong contact?

Tags: macos, contacts, facebook

I have Contact cards for my father- and brother-in-law, let's call them John Smith and Johnny Smith (he's a Junior). My father-in-law doesn't use Facebook, but my brother-in-law does, and since he goes by John Smith on Facebook, Mountain Lion associated my father-in-law's card with his account (even though I had birthdays for each card - now my father-in-law has two birthdays...).

Is there any way I can correct it to choose by brother-in-law instead? I tried disabling Contacts integration from System Preferences, then renaming them to be John Smith, Sr. and John Smith and turning it back on. It remained connected to my father-in-law.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an easier option. Go to the contact that has been merged. Click edit. Click the minus icon next to the Facebook card at the bottom of the contact. The two cards will spring apart and you will have two contacts. Hit save.

Comment: Perfect, I missed that. Great to know.

Answer (score 0):

I made a new contact card for my father-in-law (adding his middle initial and the "Sr." suffix), and deleted the original. When I turned Facebook integration back on, Facebook created its own card for my brother-in-law. From there, I was able to select the Facebook card and my original (iCloud) card, and choose Card -> Link Selected Cards from the menubar. That worked like a charm.

Apple could have helped the situation immensely by adding an opposite menu item named "Unlink Selected Cards". Then, I wouldn't have had to delete and recreate my father-in-law's card.